# Does T4MVC support WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm trying to use T4MVC to create strongly typed links to WebApi endpoints, and while it does generate helpers for my ApiControllers, there's no method for creating links.  The generated controllers have ViewNames, but no action methods.  I guess this is because `ApiController`'s don't return `ActionResult`'s, but what do I need to be doing instead to create these links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported today, but please check out [this thread](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/354067) which has some good amount of discussion about it. Feel free to reply over there to add to it.

Comment: Update today: still not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Still doesn't seem to be supported by the end of 2015.

If it's URL generation that you're concerned with, then take a look at [Drum](https://github.com/pmhsfelix/drum) if you're using attribute routing in Web.API 2+. And if you've got routes set up in your application startup (Web.API 1) then it appears [Hyperlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr) will be helpful.

If you need other things (like a hard-coded parameter list) then you're still out of luck.

*Disclaimer: I've not used either*

Comment: Thanks for the links. Will check them out.